# Как создать выпадающий список select, который будет менять изображение?

Tags: javascript, html, json, select

Имеется html и css код. Помогите написать JS для правильной работы скрипта, чтобы при выборе определенной опции менялась картинка.

```css
.catalog__item {
    padding-bottom: 550px
}
.catalog__head {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000
}
.catalog__item-img,
.catalog__item-img-2,
.catalog__item-img-3,
.catalog__item-img-4,
.catalog__item-img-5,
.catalog__item-img-6 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 230px
}
.catalog__item-color,
.catalog__item-price {
    margin-bottom: 40px
}
.catalog__item-img img,
.catalog__item-img-2 img,
.catalog__item-img-3 img,
.catalog__item-img-4 img,
.catalog__item-img-5 img,
.catalog__item-img-6 img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 190px
}
.catalog__item-img-2:before,
.catalog__item-img-3:before,
.catalog__item-img-4:before,
.catalog__item-img-5:before,
.catalog__item-img-6:before,
.catalog__item-img:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 45px;
    width: 79px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(../assets/img/icon/sound-bluet.png) center no-repeat
}
label[for*=catalog__color] {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-right: 15px
}
#catalog__color,
#catalog__color-2,
#catalog__color-3,
#catalog__color-4,
#catalog__color-5,
#catalog__color-6 {
    border: 4px solid #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 180px
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__item-img">
                  <img src="assets/img/smart/grafity.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="catalog__item-color">
                  <label for="catalog__color">Выбрать цвет</label>
                  <select name="" id="catalog__color">
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/grafity.png" value="">Графити</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/google.png" value="">Гугл</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/hacki-1.png" value="">Хаки 1</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/fire.png" value="">Огонь</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/white.png" value="">Белый</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/zebra.png" value="">Зебра</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/blue.png" value="">Синий</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/black.png" value="">Черный</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/hacki.png" value="">Хаки</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/pink.png" value="">Розовый</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/red.png" value="">Красный</option>
                    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/yellow.png" value="">Желтый</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам потребуется поймать событие изменения в `select`, получить значение `data-path` у выбранного `option` и изменить атрибут `src` у `img` на значение полученное из `option` по `data-path`

```js
$(function(){
    $("#catalog__color").bind("change", function(){
        var selectedItemValue = $("option:selected").data("path");
        $(".catalog__item-img img").attr("src", selectedItemValue);
    });
})
```

```css
.catalog__item {
    padding-bottom: 550px
}
.catalog__head {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000
}
.catalog__item-img,
.catalog__item-img-2,
.catalog__item-img-3,
.catalog__item-img-4,
.catalog__item-img-5,
.catalog__item-img-6 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 230px
}
.catalog__item-color,
.catalog__item-price {
    margin-bottom: 40px
}
.catalog__item-img img,
.catalog__item-img-2 img,
.catalog__item-img-3 img,
.catalog__item-img-4 img,
.catalog__item-img-5 img,
.catalog__item-img-6 img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 190px
}
.catalog__item-img-2:before,
.catalog__item-img-3:before,
.catalog__item-img-4:before,
.catalog__item-img-5:before,
.catalog__item-img-6:before,
.catalog__item-img:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 45px;
    width: 79px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(../assets/img/icon/sound-bluet.png) center no-repeat
}
label[for*=catalog__color] {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-right: 15px
}
#catalog__color,
#catalog__color-2,
#catalog__color-3,
#catalog__color-4,
#catalog__color-5,
#catalog__color-6 {
    border: 4px solid #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 180px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog__item-img">
  <img src="assets/img/smart/grafity.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="catalog__item-color">
  <label for="catalog__color">Выбрать цвет</label>
  <select name="" id="catalog__color">
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/grafity.png" value="">Графити</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/google.png" value="">Гугл</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/hacki-1.png" value="">Хаки 1</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/fire.png" value="">Огонь</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/white.png" value="">Белый</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/zebra.png" value="">Зебра</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/blue.png" value="">Синий</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/black.png" value="">Черный</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/hacki.png" value="">Хаки</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/pink.png" value="">Розовый</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/red.png" value="">Красный</option>
    <option data-path="assets/img/smart/yellow.png" value="">Желтый</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам !!!